# How to display options as group under a label using <p-autocomplete> PrimeNG 6.1.0

Tags: angular, primeng

Autocomplete shows a list of suggestions when a user search. I am trying to show the list of options as a grouped suggestions as shown below and the labels like Fruits/Vegetables should not be clickable or highlighted/selected by the user when user search for  a  word "Mi":

**Label1**
  Mind
  Minimum
  Minute
**Label2**
  Mirror
  Mirrage

I am pushing all the items in list "allItems". 
html file looks like this:

```html
    
    <p-autoComplete  [suggestions]="allItems"
                    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                  [(ngModel)]="searchedItems"
                  (completeMethod)="onSearchFieldKeyUp($event)" 
                  [autoHighlight]="true">
    </p-autoComplete>
```

Comment: I have resolved this by adding an index field along with the text field as on object of elements to be displayed.
listItem=[{index:Fruit_Header, text:Fruit}, {index:Mind, text:Mind},....]

Comment: <ng-template let-dataItem pTemplate="text">
                    <div *ngIf="dataItem.value.includes('header'); else Items" class='unclickable-header'>